# Sonar Runner fails with exception with rule

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to publish to Sonar using Gradle on a Java 8 project which is failing with the following error:

```
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time: 1:18.786s
    Final Memory: 25M/764M
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
    ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
    ERROR: Caused by: Rule 'squid:S1192' can not use 'Constant/issue' remediation function because this rule does not have a fixed remediation cost.
```

If I select my project to use the *FindBugs* quality profile then everything works and stats are uploaded to sonar. However if I turn on the *sonar way* profile the error above is thrown.

Looking at the error it seems it cannot find a remediation cost (which I think is required to work out how many days it will take to fix all tech debt)

I have tried uninstalling other plugins (JavaScript/Python/etc) and just leave Java. I have also tried tweaking the defaults in the Technical Debt settings. I have restored the default profiles also. All have had no effect.

I am using the following versions:

- sonar 5.0.1 (application)
- sonar-runner 2.4 (gradle plugin)
- gradle 2.3
- java 8 (project to analyse)
- java plugin 3.1 (sonar plugin)

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Looks like that exception is [thrown here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-batch/src/main/java/org/sonar/batch/issue/ModuleIssues.java#L138) But I'm not sure what you can do to get around it...

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. I'll look into what 'DebtRemediationFunction' type that rule is supposed to be and look into  *effortToFix*

Comment: Could you provide the version of the java plugin used ?

Comment: Did you upgrade java plugin recently ? from which version ? it seems like the Sqale debt of this rule (S1192) is badly configured hence causing the issue you see. If you have sqale plugin you can update it from interface.

Comment: We upgraded the Java plugin from 2.1 to 3.1 along with a sonar upgrade from 4.2 to 5.0.1 to accommodate Java 8. We don't have the SQALE plugin but I guess that sonar provides a "cut down" SQALE. I could try adding the SQALE plugin and see if it sorts out the squid rules

Comment: This issue is very strange : the effort to fix is not fixed by the SQALE plugin or by the SonarQube platform, it's set by language plugin (here by the findbugs plugin).
Could you send us your server's log (logs/sonar.log) ?  I need to see the list of your plugins with the git hashes.

Comment: Hi Julien - I have an feeling that this issue may have been caused by the way we have upgraded our system (I need to confirm this with someone on Monday). But I _think_ the database may have become corrupted during a clone. We have a current instance of sonar 4.2 running and in use and I was testing sonar 5.0.1 and a clone was made of the database. I will confirm this on Monday and let you know. The reason I say this is I have installed a local version and it publishes fine. Is there a preferred method to upgrade and keep history? Thanks

Comment: @JulienLancelot - I have done a fresh install of sonar and everything works. The problem appears when an upgrade is done to an existing database

Comment: Can you explain me what " have an feeling that this issue may have been caused by the way we have upgraded our system" ? How did you upgrade your system ? Have you dropped the data/es folder before upgrading ?

Comment: We installed version 5.0.1 of sonar on a new server, then tested it and everything worked (sonar way rules passed). We then cloned the database of our existing sonar 4.2 version and called the /setup url, but analysis failed with error above

Comment: Did you removed the /data/es folder before switching the db ? If not, that the root origin of your issue

Comment: It was a fresh install on a new server, so the folder won't exist. We then cloned the DB schema and pointed the new sonar at it then called the /setup URL. When analysing the following rules fail if activated. _MethodCyclomaticComplexity_, _S1192_, _S135_, _S1067_

Comment: As the schema has changed, you need to remove again the es folder, because the es folder is synchronized with the schema. If the schema is manually updated, the es folder MUST be dropped. Thanks

Comment: In fact you have to follow steps described in the description of https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5335 to sanitize your rules technical debt definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get the 4 problematic rules to work by doing the following:

The first tables shows the state of the database from a completely fresh install

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ PLUGIN_NAME ║      PLUGIN_RULE_KEY       ║ REMEDIATION_FUNCTION ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ squid       ║ MethodCyclomaticComplexity ║ (null)               ║
║ squid       ║ S1067                      ║ (null)               ║
║ squid       ║ S1192                      ║ (null)               ║
║ squid       ║ S135                       ║ (null)               ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

This table show the state of the database from a fresh install pointing to a cloned database and running the /setup URL.

**NOTE:** This is still a fresh install and in a new directory so the /es directory will not exist [Step 3 followed here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ PLUGIN_NAME ║      PLUGIN_RULE_KEY       ║ REMEDIATION_FUNCTION ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ squid       ║ MethodCyclomaticComplexity ║ CONSTANT_ISSUE       ║
║ squid       ║ S1067                      ║ CONSTANT_ISSUE       ║
║ squid       ║ S1192                      ║ CONSTANT_ISSUE       ║
║ squid       ║ S135                       ║ CONSTANT_ISSUE       ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

To solve this I had set the values in the `REMEDIATION_FUNCTION` back to `null` and the rules now work.

```
update rules
set remediation_function = null
where plugin_name = 'squid'
and plugin_rule_key in ('MethodCyclomaticComplexity', 'S1192', 'S135', 'S1067')
```

Comment: Good catch ! Indeed, when coming from SonarQube version <= 4.3, the technical debt definitions of rules need to be reset. In order to sanitize all rules, you should follow the steps described in the description of  https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5335

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading from SonarQube 4.3 or before, the technical debt definitions of the rules MUST be reset :

**Without the SQALE plugin :**

- Execute the SQL query : "UPDATE rules SET characteristic_id=NULL, remediation_function=NULL, remediation_coeff=NULL, remediation_offset=NULL WHERE characteristic_id IS NOT NULL;"
- Remove the data/es folder (if exists)
- Restart your server.

**With the SQALE plugin :**

- Go to the update center and install the SQALE plugin (if not already installed)
- Go to the 'Back Up Model' page (Settings -> SQALE -> Back Up / Restore)
- In the Restore Model section, click on the 'Restore' button -> your quality model will be reset, all overridden rules technical debt definitions will be reset.
- Go to the update center and uninstall the SQALE plugin (if it was not installed before).

This ticket https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5056 is at the origin of this required change.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after update from version 4.2 to 4.5.4. To continue my project analysis I had to deactivate following rules:

- squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity
- squid:S1192
- squid:S135

All of them throws "can not use 'Constant/issue' remediation function because this rule does not have a fixed remediation cost" error.

My installation use Java 8, sonar-runner 2.4 and following plugins:

- sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.2.jar
- sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar
- sonar-java-plugin-3.1.jar
- sonar-javascript-plugin-2.4.jar
- sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar
- sonar-scm-activity-plugin-1.8.jar

Comment: Hi @mberkan - I have deactivated the above rules (plus S1067) to get it publishing statistics. However this is not the correct thing to do. Those rules are valid rules and by deactivating them I will miss genuine violations :-(

Comment: You right, but it's only one way which I found to pass the analysis. Finally, as you mentioned above, we have to set up fresh copy of Sonar but then we will lost all historical information. I hope somebody find better resolution.

Comment: Have you dropped the data/es folder before upgrading ?

Comment: Please read http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading#Upgrading-HowtoUpgrade, point 8

Comment: I didn't check it, but I assumed that if it is a fresh install, then it shouldn't exist...

Comment: Indeed, it has nothing to do with ES, sorry. It relates to the fact that we change the technical debt definition of the rules, please follow steps described in the description of https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5335